# Creating non-curve circles in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

How can I create circles that do not contain curves in ArcGIS 10.2?

I am capturing data into a personal geodatabase. Using the create circle tool. The data is later exported from the personal geodatabse using ogr2ogr, which does not support the extraction of curves from personal geodatabases into shapefiles.

So is there a way to draw circles as a series of lines rather then as a single curve?

Or is there a way to convert the circles into polygons later?

Comment: Which version of GDAL are you using?

Comment: 2.0.2 I based my assumption of no curve support on: http://lists.maptools.org/pipermail/fwtools/2008-November/001430.html Also I could not get curves to display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert such circles into polygons I copy them out to a shapefile (which does not support curves) and then copy them back in to a geodatabase feature class.

The result is a vertexed curve.

I use this technique for using circular buffers constructed in a Projected Coordinate System to make selections against data (that I am not permitted to project) which is stored in a Geographic Coordinate System.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the easiest solution.

Comment: Or build directly to a shapefile, then convert to geodatabase feature class.